# Are the clusters in a cluster graph complete graphs?

Tags: graphs

I read two definitions of cluster graphs that seem in conflict to me. One is from Koller:

> We begin by defining a *cluster graph* — a data structure that provides a graphical flowchart of
> the factor-manipulation process. Each node in the cluster graph is a *cluster*, which is associated
> with a subset of variables; the graph contains undirected edges that connect clusters whose
> scopes have some non-empty intersection. We note that this definition is more general than the
> data structures we use in this chapter, but this generality will be important in the next chapter,
> where we significantly extend the algorithms of this chapter.
>
> Definition 10.1: A cluster graph $\mathcal{U}$ for a set of factors $\Phi$ over $\mathcal{X}$ is an undirected graph, each of whose nodes $i$ is associated with a subset $\boldsymbol{C}_i \subseteq \mathcal{X}$ . A cluster graph must be family-preserving — each factor $\phi \in \Phi$
> must be associated with a cluster $\boldsymbol{C}_i$, denoted $\alpha(\phi)$, such that $\text{Scope}[\phi] \subseteq \boldsymbol{C}_i$. Each edge between
> a pair of clusters $\boldsymbol{C}_i$ and $\boldsymbol{C}_j$ is associated with a sepset $\boldsymbol{S}_{i,j} \subseteq \boldsymbol{C}_i \cap \boldsymbol{C}_j$.

Then I saw another definition on Wikipedia

Source: page 346, Koller, Daphne, and Nir Friedman. *Probabilistic graphical models: principles and techniques.* MIT press, 2009.

> In graph theory, a branch of mathematics, a cluster graph is a graph formed from the disjoint union of complete graphs. Equivalently, a graph is a cluster graph if and only if it has no three-vertex induced path; for this reason, the cluster graphs are also called $P_{3}$-free graphs.

Source: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_graph#:~:text=In%20graph%20theory%2C%20a%20branch,called%20P3%2Dfree%20graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_graph#:%7E:text=In%20graph%20theory%2C%20a%20branch,called%20P3%2Dfree%20graphs).

Unless I am reading this wrong, Koller's definition makes no requirement for completeness. According to Koller's definition, it seems to me that each $\boldsymbol{C}_{i}$ need only be a subset of $\mathcal{X}$ with an arbitrary configuration of edges within the cluster, no specification that it need be a complete graph.

If I am correct these definitions are incompatible, can someone explain which one is correct?

If I am incorrect, I'd love to know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading it correctly.  Those are two different uses of the word "cluster graph".

In graph theory, and usually in computer science, when you refer to a *cluster graph* it is of the latter kind.

For graph classes, the holy scripture is `graphclasses.org`, in which you can find [Graphclass: cluster](https://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_1237.html)

> **Graphclass**: cluster
>
> Definition:
>
> A graph is a cluster graph if it is a disjoint union of cliques.
>
> **Equivalent classes**:
>
> - 2-leaf power
> - $P_3$-free